# limit of reciprocal of function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that  $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \ell$ where $\ell \in \mathbb R$. Prove that

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(1/x^2) = \ell$.

Does this involve reciprocal of functions? I am guessing that if $f(x) = \ell$ as $x \to \infty$, then $f(1/x^2)$ as $x$ goes to 0 will be same as $f(x)$ as $x \to \infty$. Therefore the limit will be same. Am I right?

Thanks.

Comment: You are on the right trace!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, there exits an $N > 0$ such that:

If $x > N$ $\Rightarrow$ $|f(x) - \ell| < \epsilon$.

Now choose $\delta = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$, then if $0 < |x| < \delta \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{x^2} > N \Rightarrow |f(1/x^2) - \ell| < \epsilon$. The conclusion follows.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: take  $\displaystyle t=\frac{1}{x^2}\implies  x\to0\implies t\to \infty$